# Animate a "print" element with raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I would like to know if it is possible to animate `print` properly with raphaeljs?

Because something like this:

```
var text = paper.print(10,10,"Text here",Font,20).animate({transform:"t100,100"},500);
```

doesn't work at all...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Raphael's documentation says `.print()` returns a set, so you would need to treat it as such...

```
var text = paper.print(10,10,"Text here",Font,20)
text.forEach(function(){
  this.animate({transform:"t100,100"},500);
})
```

I must say that I tried your code and `text` returns an empty array, but you might have better luck.